# How to let users sign up with their email addresses in CouchDB safely

Tags: javascript, json, security, couchdb

I'm working on an html5 application built on CouchDB. I want to make sure I set up the user data in the best way possible.

I'd like to use an email address in the "name" field of the user documents in the _user database. Like so:

```
{
   "_id": "org.couchdb.user:John",
   "_rev": "1-e25df7d685c35dbeb8dabb2453adebe8",
   "name": "john@test.com",
   "salt": "32ef0f8b1651e0638080afc76d0111d6",
   "password_sha": "3023d37579fee19acd01d88c3ae1921a000418d7",
   "type": "user",
   "roles": [
   ]
}
```

The reason I would like to do this, is because an email address is a very unambiguous thing to ask for at sign up, and it is guaranteed to be unique amongst users. It requires the least amount of thought on the part of the user, and it's super simple. There's a problem though. If the _user database is public, then so are the email addresses in the user documents as far as I can tell. How can I overcome that?

Should I make the _user database private (readable and writeable only by admins?)
Should I store user data in individual user databases, and if I do that, how can my applications then pull that data efficiently. If I have several user's data displayed on one page, with other data from other databases doesn't that start to become really inefficient?

A little lost here, would love to know how some people have dealt with private user data.

Comment: What's wrong with using the email as the key but only displaying a handle, like every other site in the world?  In your example are all of the passwords public?  They're evidently in the user database also.

Comment: Hmmm...there's probably nothing wrong with that at all. I'm just fairly new as a developer, how would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used couchdb, but I just did some reading in response to your question...

I read the Security and Validation section of the [Technical Overview](http://couchdb.apache.org/docs/overview.html).

Also the wiki: [Security_Features_Overvie -- Authentication_database](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Security_Features_Overview#Authentication_database)

**_id and name must match** As the wiki says:

> > The "_id" attribute value must be prefixed with the string "org.couchdb.user:" and the rest must match the value of the attribute "name".

Thus

```
{
   # won't work: "_id": "org.couchdb.user:John",
   "_id": "org.couchdb.user:john@test.com" # try this
   "_rev": "1-e25df7d685c35dbeb8dabb2453adebe8",
   "name": "john@test.com",
   "salt": "32ef0f8b1651e0638080afc76d0111d6",
   "password_sha": "3023d37579fee19acd01d88c3ae1921a000418d7",
   "type": "user",
   "roles": [
   ]
}
```

However

1. The user name can't start with an underscore
2. Not clear from the docs if the user name can include @ . + and other symbols used by email names. *You'll need to try it.*

**Authentication and Access Control of _user doc**

Re should _user db be private? Yes, it must be private. Also, in the current version of CouchDB, the user db has special security and access controls. This was done to take care of the same issues that you are struggling with.

From the same [authentication database](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Security_Features_Overview#Authentication_database) section of the wiki:

> > ... the _users database is now treated different from other databases:
> >
> > An anonymous user can only create a new document.
> >
> > An authenticated user can only update their own document.

This means that your software can enable people to create new accounts safely. Once they are authenticated, they can only view/modify their own _user information.

Comment: Okay, so much helpful information, thank you! ....reading..... Okay, I read through the links you sent along, and it seems CouchDB handles much of the heavy lifting. So the permissions, it seems, are automatically set up such that users can only edit their own data. This leaves me wondering though, read permission is open to anyone? So if users add data via some application to their user document, anyone can go and read that info? Thanks again for the help!

Comment: @Costa: glad to help. I was also looking for the answer to your exact point. It isn't clear from the docs. My guess is that you don't want _users to have read world and that it usually is NOT read_world. Note that you can also add your own view sw which controls access to docs. You can also create additional databases that hold your additional user info but the other databases can have different permission setup. I suggest you try the couchdb forums. You should also add your experiences to their wiki to improve it. It is common for young projects to not have great docs, couchdb is an example.

Comment: Larry thanks so much! Very helpful stuff, and I know exactly what to explore next.  It's troubling though.  Part of the reason I'm loving CouchDB is because it's so open, but at the same time, that creates risks, not just with private user data, but also with public database documents.  Thanks again!